# Returning values from a function in Python3 with correct formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, formatting

working on a coding program that I think I have licked and I'm getting the correct values for.  However the test conditions are looking for the values formatted in a different way.  And I'm failing at figuring out how to format the return in my function correctly.

I get the values correctly when looking for the answer:

[4, 15, 7, 19, 1, 20, 13, 9, 4, 14, 9, 7, 8, 20]

but the test condition expects

should equal '20 8 5 14 1 18 23 8 1 12 2 1 3 15 14 19 1 20 13 9 4 14 9 7 8 20'

and for the life of me I haven't been able to figure this out yet.

View the original problem here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/546f922b54af40e1e90001da/train/python

Still very new to Python, but tackling these problems best I can. Code may be ugly, but it's mine =D

EDIT: I am looking for a way to reformat my return statement as a string instead of a list of integers.

Thanks for the help in advance!  Any help is appreciated, even how to post better questions here.

Koruptedkernel.

```
import string

def alphabet_position(positions):
    #Declaring final position list.
    position = []
    #Stripping punctuation from the passed string.
    out1 = positions.translate(str.maketrans("","", string.punctuation))
    #Stripping digits from the passed string.
    out = out1.translate(str.maketrans("","", string.digits))
    #Removing Spaces from the passed string.
    outter = out.replace(" ","")
    #reducing to lowercase.
    mod_text = str.lower(outter)
    #For loop to iterate through alphabet and report index location to position list.
    for letter in mod_text:
        #Declare list of letters (lower) in the alphabet (US).
        alphabet = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        position.append(alphabet.index(letter) + 1)
    return(position)

#Call the function with text.
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o'clock.")
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to convert a list to a string? Because your program does give the correct list for the given input.

Comment: Your main idea/question in this post is not understandable, furthermore your code has indentation errors. Please re-edit your post

Comment: Edited comment to fix indents in code.

Comment: Am I better off changing the position variable to a string and then returning it? I tried it a few times and failed (only returns [] after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your homework with some explanations (uses a comprehension which are the BEST):

```py
# full alphabet (is technically a list)
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
# letter and index+1 for each letter
alphabet_dict = {u: str(i + 1) for i, u in enumerate(alphabet)}

def alphabet_position(text):
    # map the text chars to their corresponding aplhabet_dict item
    pos_list = [alphabet_dict.get(char.lower())
                for char in text if char.lower() in alphabet_dict]
    # convert to the insane string format they asked for
    return ' '.join(pos_list)

alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
```

Output:

```py
'20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Had some great homework with dictionaries and tried and successfully did it THAT way.

Went back to the original way I did it (not as clean or efficient), but managed to get the list successfully converted by changing my for loop to

```
position.append(str(alphabet.index(letter) + 1))
```

and then used

```
return ' '.join(position)
```

to get the answer in the format they were test for.

YES! I SOLVED A THING!

Thanks for all the help, I will try and get better at formulating questions to get better help.

TYTY